# Does gaussian elimination always work?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, gaussian-elimination

If so, why don't we use that to get from any square matrix to a triangular matrix - from which can be deduced eigenvalues, determinant (product of eigenvalues) and diagonal matrix (since the diagonal elements are the eigenvalues) - rather than using the characteristic polynomial, eigenvectors and $D = P^{-1}AP$  ?

Comment: Eigenvalues are not invariant under the process of Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Gaussian elimination requires the ability to compute whether a value is equal to zero or not...in some algebraic situations, that information may not be available, in which case Gaussian elimination would not "work".

Comment: So if I Gauss a matrix A to a triangular matrix T, I might end up with different eigenvalues than those of A ? But why does it work for determinants then ?

Comment: The operations in Gaussian method are equivalent to multiplication by a matrix whose determinant is $\pm 1$.  That doesn't change whether or not the determinant is 0, but it almost certainly changes the eigenvalues.